# Split String by Multiple Delimiters in PHP

Tags: php

Can strings be parsed into an array based on multiple delimiters? as explained in the code:

```
$str ="a,b c,d;e f";
//What i want is to convert this string into array
//using the delimiters space, comma, semicolon
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### PHP

```
$str = "a,b c,d;e f";

$pieces = preg_split('/[, ;]/', $str);

var_dump($pieces);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/Fp367H1f).

#### Output

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "d"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "e"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "f"
}
```

Comment: You know, in all my time using PHP I've never once had to use that function--but it's nice to know that it exists. Very cool.

Comment: @KyleFarris I often use it when splitting user entered input on comma, instead of using `explode()`, `array_map()` and `trim()`, I've been using `preg_split('/,\s*/', $csv)`.

Comment: That was perfectly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

strtok --> http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php

Comment: You'd have to call strtok multiple times to build your array, strtok alone doesn't build the array, just returns string parts one at a time