# Split string with multiple delimiters

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have seen many (before you go flagging this as a duplicate) on how to do this, but for some reason my output isn't working:

```
// $delimiters wanted: ', ' | '; ' | ',' | ';' | ' , ' | ', and ' | ' and ' | ',and '
$str = 'Name 1, Name 2; Name 3;Name4 , Name 5,Name 6, and Name 7,and Name 8 and Name 9';
$delimiter = array(
    ', ',
    '; ',
    ';',
    ',',
    ' , ',
    ', and ',
    ' and ',
    ',and '
);
$str_new = explode( $delimiter[0], str_replace($delimiter, $delimiter[0], $str) );
```

However, when I output the array, I get this:

```
<?php foreach($str_new as $new) { echo 'a' . $new; } ?>

Array (
    [0] => Name 1
    [1] => Name 2
    [2] => Name 3
    [3] =>        // WHY IS THIS EMPTY?
    [4] => Name 4
    ...
)
```

So is there a better way to match the delimiters I have listed?

Comment: the space is at the wrong place by name4! can you change that to name 4 and not name4

Comment: @caramba I wanted to show that there is also cases where there is a space before and after the comma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use regexp like this in your case:

```php
preg_split('/,? ?and | ?[,;] ?/', $str)
```

You may also want to replace spaces by `\s` if the other space characters may appear (like TAB, for example) or even `\s*` instead of `?` to cover the case of multiple spaces.

Comment: This works! How intensive is it though compared to `explode`? Would it take over 100 to see an impact? I really only have under 20 in the string.

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv I don't know the exact values, but functions using regular expressions are usually slower than simple string ones. So, in most cases `explode` should be faster (I feel, about 5 times) than `preg_split`. But in our case `explode` method is slowed down by internal replaces (`preg_replace` or `str_replace`).

Comment: Well it looks like 3 other upvotes to you compared to the other. It works too, and in one line. Plus you even went beyond with the TAB.

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv Thanks. I've compared the speed of both approaches. `explode`/`str_replace` is only 1.6x faster than `preg_split` on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this from php.net?

```
<?php

//$delimiters has to be array
//$string has to be array

function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}

$text = "here is a sample: this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)";
$exploded = multiexplode(array(",",".","|",":"),$text);

print_r($exploded);
?>
```

Or something like [Split String by Multiple Delimiters in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414916/split-string-by-multiple-delimiters-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: I have tried this but adding `", and "` and `" and "` seems to stuff things up.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, between `Name 6, and Name 7`, first the `,` gets replaced, then the `and`.

Therefore you end up with this string:

> Name 1, Name 2, Name 3, Name4, Name 5, Name 6, , Name 7, Name 8, Name 9

Hence, the empty value...

Clean your result array before outputting and you should be fine:

```
$str_out = array_filter($str_new);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your approach is, that you want to solve a problem using the wrong way. Even if you manage to create a list of delimiters, what happens if you need e.g. separate the words by another character, let's say, a '$' sign?

You should implement a tokenizer/lexer which reads the input char by char and distinguishes between white spaces, terminal and non terminal symbols/characters. The lexer would then generate a sequence of token, e.g.

```
STRING-SYMBOL:'NAME1' 
KOMMA-SYMBOL 
AND-SYMBOL 
STRING-SYMBOL:'NAME2' 
SEMICOLON-SYMBOL 
STRING-SYMBOL:'NAME3' 
AND-SYMBOL
...
EOF-SYMBOL
```

You then simply filter out any non `STRING-SYMBOL` symbols (or you combine strings using the `AND-SYMBOL`. This is (imho) the only rock solid solution. It is also very easy to extend and to generalize: Once you have written a nice tokenizer/lexer, you can use this approach for almost any string analyzing problem.

Writing a tokenizer is generally very simple: It scans the input char by char and first categorizes the char. It implements a simple state machine to collect characters which will form a symbol.

You may try to implement this using a regex, which should be possible as well. Anyway, the tokenizer will generate a list of token (or will retrieve the next one upon request). The last token it will retrieve is the `EOF-TOKEN` indicating that the input sequence has been fully traversed.

Comment: Why does this answer completely ignore the question's sample data/context?

Comment: What makes you think that this answer "completely ignore the question's sample data/context". It describes how to implement a tokenizer for the language defined by the question's sample data. Maybe you do not understand what I was referring to 9 years ago

Comment: `$str = 'Name 1, Name 2; Name 3;Name4 , Name 5,Name 6, and Name 7,and Name 8 and Name 9';`  It is not surprising that this answer has not been marked as helpful by anyone in nearly a decade.  It is a theoretical/academic piece that doesn't actually demonstrate how to code a resolving approach.   You may wish to [edit] your post to make it more helpful to researchers.